# Posting a random image from directory to twitter

Tags: python, twitter, twython

So I'm working on a little mini project running off of a raspberry pi, of which the end goal is to have the pi running a python script to post a random image from a directory to twitter (a twitter bot).  I have this code so far, and I'm getting an error.  I'm assuming that the error is caused due to the fact that it is somehow not receiving the correct file type, but I'm not 100% sure.  A little help would be fantastic!

```
import os
import random
from twython import Twython
#removed keys for privacy reasons
CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_KEY = ''
ACCESS_SECRET = ''
twitter = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
path = '/home/pi/DailyMeme/Memes/downloaded_images'
count = 0
file_list = []
for filename in os.listdir(path):
        count = count+1
        file_list.append(filename)

rnd = random.randint(0,count)
photo = open('/home/pi/DailyMeme/Memes/downloaded_images/'+file_list[rnd]+'.jpg','rb')
response = twitter.upload_media(media=photo)
twitter.update_status(status='check out this random meme', media_ids[response['media_id']])
```

EDIT: I'm new to python so it would be great if you could explain to me solutions

Error Message

```
File "random_meme.py", line 20
    twitter.update_status(status='check out this random meme' , media_ids[response['media_id']])
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

Comment: Also include the full error message if possible.

Comment: Care to tell us what the error message is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that once you have a keyword in the function call, in this case `status` all the following parameters in the function call must include a keyword.
Therefore you'll need to call this function either in different order of parameters or add a keyword to the second parameter

```
twitter.update_status(status='check out this random meme' , some_keyword=media_ids[response['media_id']])
```

(This is at least part of the issue regardless to what you actually want to achieve)